# TextView + WebView

Tags: android, textview, android-webview

[image]I am using TextView as of yet to display both text and URL, but I want an architecture where I can use both TextView as well as Webview. WebView will be  `visible-gone` and only Enable it when `"https//"` appears in my TextView. How do I go about it? Please help

Comment: u want webview to appear automatically

Comment: if url is https in the view

Comment: Yes ya.. is that possible?

Comment: u want the webview on click of link

Comment: I have added an image in my question for referral. I want both the text as well as the webpage.

Comment: No, i want the text and my webview below it without any click. Also the link is not given my me. Its dynamic and comes from the Database in some particular situations.

Comment: @SabihaTaskin like whatsApp when link appears you want to display metadata?

Comment: you can use `youtext.contains("https//")` , if `false` disable webview else enable it using View.Gone etc

Comment: Yes you can say like whatsapp, but instead of the metadata it has to be the whole content of the webpage.

Comment: what if two https is available in the text

Comment: @Athul In my use-case it wont. It will be just one URL with https

Comment: You can use a url extract from textview and check using another condition if it is https or not. So after this condition u can create a layout below the textview for webview which u can control visibility

Comment: @SabihaTaskin did u get wt i tried to tell

Comment: u can keep the layout with webview as visibilty gone first and control its visibilty using the condition

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. But my output consist of both text and url (on above image). I tried the `text.consist("http://");` to segregate them both, I will update if the code works. Thanks

Comment: If your issue has been sorted out, please select the best answer. If you have some follow up questions, consider commenting on the particular answers. Thanks!

Comment: @MohammadAhsan I am still figuring it out as its not quite solved yet.

Comment: I tried this `String s = output.getText().toString();
        if (
                s.contains("http://")
                ) {
            web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            web.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }` But still my output is same as above image.

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the entire code from the activity handling this?

Comment: I double checked if my application is understanding an URL, when it apprears(checked it by using a Toast). And yes it does recognizes a url, but my webview visible and loading that particular url is not happening. I have edited code above.

Comment: if I use `web.loadurl("www.google.com");` it then loads. But i want to load the url I received dynamically at my TextView. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can check dynamically if the string in your TextView contains the substring "https". An easy way to do this would be something like this:

```
String s = myTextView.getText().toString();
if s.contains("https"){
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = output.getText().toString();
    if ( url.contains("http://") )
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello URL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        web.loadUrl(url);

    }else
    { web.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

I solved using the above code. Thanks all for the help.